# Tool to copy SQL Server Database

Tags: sql, ssms

I am looking for a tool to copy a sql database tables, stored procedures, functions etc and also the data contained within the database from a server to my local pc. Both have sql server management studio 2008 installed. Any tools that would be recommended to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do a backup and then restore it on your PC, or you can detach the database and copy the logs and db and reattach on both your pc and the server.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free xSQL Bundle edition that may work for you, in case you need to keep the two databases in sync ([URL](http://www.xsqlsoftware.com/LiteEdition.aspx---)). The limitations of the lite edition are:

- up to 25 tables
- up to 40 views
- up to 40 stored procedures
- up to 40 functions

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, if you can temporarily bring the server offline/detach the Database is to copy the MDF and LDF files, copy them over and reattach them on your computer.

Otherwise, the SQL Server BACKUP and RESTORE commands will work well.

If you have access to SQL Server Management Studio, it can be done from the GUI by right-clicking on the database's icon and using the items in the contextual menu.

Comment: That isn't another alternative - it is "copy the logs and db". :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do it on a regular basis (say from a production machine to a development machine), take a look at the Red Gate tools @ http://www.red-gate.com/

I use the software frequently for determining changes to schema or for syncing data between my production machines and local development machines.  The software isn't free but worth the money if you have the need.